# Angular route parameter from parent cannot be retrieved

Tags: angular, routes

I have a strange issue where I have the following route setup:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CustomerControlPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'add',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: AddCustomerViewComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'edit/:id',
        component: EditCustomerViewComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'user',
            component: CustomerAddUserViewComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'select',
                component: CustomerAddUserSelectViewComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full'
              },
              {
                path: '',
                component: CustomerAddUserBaseViewComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            path: 'app',
            component: CustomerAddAppViewComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'select',
                component: CustomerAddAppSelectViewComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full'
              },
              {
                path: '',
                component: CustomerAddAppBaseViewComponent,
                pathMatch: 'full'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: CustomerEditBaseViewComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full' 
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: CustomerViewComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I can see at the component under the URL "edit/:id/user" can't retrieve the URL parameter 'id' from the parent component.

Normally I can get the URL parameter of the parent using the following code, in my case the parent paramMap is always null.

```js
this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
   console.log(param.get('id'))
});
```

If I want to read the parameter id using the following code I get a null object back:

```js
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(param => {
   console.log(param.get('id'));
});
```

Am I missing something? Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: What if you try with `this.activatedRoute.parent.params` like here https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-parent-routing-params ?

Comment: For me params is also null in this case.